# For loop in C langage

Tags: c, function

I have two functions, one for calculate the min and the max of an array the seconde one is for calculate the average of this array:

```
void find_min_max(double *tab, int nb, double *pmin, double *pmax) {
    double val_min, val_max;
    int i;
    val_min = tab[0];
    val_max = tab[0];
    for (i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
        if (tab[i] < val_min) {
            val_min = tab[i];
        } else
        if (tab[i] > val_max) {
            val_max = tab[i];
        }
    }
    *pmin = val_min;
    *pmax = val_max;
}

double find_average(double *tab, int nb) {
    double average, sum;
    int i;
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
        sum = sum + tab[i];
    }
    average = sum / nb;
    return average;
}
```

the array that I want to find the min, the max and the average of is a text file that contains floating point numbers:

```
int main() {
    int i, j;
    float tab[100] max, min, avg = 0;
    FILE *mydata;
    FILE *data_res;

    f = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    new_f = fopen("data_res.txt", "w");

    if (mydata == NULL)
        printf("Error");
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            fscanf(mydata, "%f", &tab[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (j = i; j < 5; j++) {
                fprintf(data_res, "%f  ", tab[j]);
                avg = find_average(tab);
                find_min_max(tab, nb, &min, &max);
            }

            fprintf(new_f, "MAX = %lf\n", max);
            fprintf(new_f, "MIN  = %lf\n", min);
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is it does not calculate the correct max and the correct min

Comment: The first argument to `find_min_max` is always the start of `tab`. Did you mean `find_min_max(&tab[j], 5, &min, &max);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `n` is not defined, the reading loop does not compile
- you should test the return value of `fscanf()` to detect conversion errors and avoid undefined behavior.
- you pass the address of `float` variables to functions that expect `double` pointers. You should use `double` for all values.
- it is unclear why you use `1196` for the computing loop
- it is unclear why you want to compute the average 5 values at a time.
- you do not pass the size of the array in `avg = find_average(tab);`
- you always compute the min and max of the first 5 values in `find_min_max(tab, 5, &min, &max);`
- `tab_C` and `b` are not defined.

You must explain what you want the code to do with these values. As posted, it is unclear what your intent is from the reading the code.

To compute the running average, min and max, you should modify your code this way:
            // compute the average of 5 elements starting at tab[i]
            avg = find_average(tab + i, 5);
            find_min_max(tab + i, 5, &min, &max);

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void find_min_max(const double *tab, int nb, double *pmin, double *pmax) {
    double val_min, val_max;
    val_min = val_max = tab[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < nb; i++) {
        if (tab[i] < val_min) {
            val_min = tab[i];
        } else
        if (tab[i] > val_max) {
            val_max = tab[i];
        }
    }
    *pmin = val_min;
    *pmax = val_max;
}

double find_average(const double *tab, int nb) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
        sum += tab[i];
    }
    return sum / nb;
}

int main() {
    int i, j;
    double tab[1200], tab_C[1200], max, min, avg = 0, H, L, x = 0.2;
    FILE *mydata;
    FILE *data_res;

    file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    data_res = fopen("data_res.txt", "w");

    if (mydata == NULL || data_res == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open files\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < 1200; i++)
            if (fscanf(mydata, "%lf", &tab[i]) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Input error at index %d\n", i);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 1196; i++) {
            //this loop is for taking 5 elements by 5
            for (j = i; j < i + 5; j++) {
                fprintf(data_res, "%f  ", tab[j]);
            }
            fprintf(data_res, "\n");
            avg = find_average(tab + i, 5);
            find_min_max(tab + i, 5, &min, &max);
            L = avg - ((avg - min) * b);
            H = avg + ((max - avg) * b);

            fprintf(data_res, "MAX = %f\n", max);
            fprintf(data_res, "MIN = %f\n", min);
            fprintf(data_res, "the average = %f\n", avg);
            fprintf(data_res, "low value = %f\n", L);
            fprintf(data_res, "High value = %f\n", H);
        }
        fclose(mydata);
        fclose(data_res);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a text file contains `1200 elements` (float numbers ) and the code should take `5 elements by 5`
step 1 : find the average then find the `max` and the`min` then it should find the value of `H` and the` L`.
I change `n` by `1200` in the loop
 I change all the types by `float` 
I changed `b` by `x`

Comment: @coder987: by 5 elements at a time, do you mean a running slice of 5 values? There are indeed 1200-4 such slices in your array. By *find the avg, min and max* do you mean the average of the slice or that of the complete array? The specification must be more precise.

Comment: Why did you declare tab as const in function find_average ?

Comment: @coder987: because the function `find_average` does not modify the contents of the array pointed to by its argument, this argument should be defined as a `const int *`. With this definition, the function can be called with a `const int *` or an `int *` value. This approach called constification helps detect unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 0):

In find_min_max, try using this:

```
if (tab[i] > val_max)
    {
    val_max = tab[i];
    }
```

instead of

```
else if (tab[i] > val_max)
        {
            val_max = tab[i];
        }
```

Comment: It's not possible for the same element to be both less than and greater than all previous elements, so this shouldn't change anything.

Comment: We are actually comparing against 2 different values (min and max), so I can think of cases where this might make a difference, so I asked to try if this might be the issue. If it is, then I can update my answer to include an explanation